# Is there a good Ambience theme for Xubuntu (XFCE, XFWM)?

Tags: themes, xfce, ambiance

Looks ridiculous, but I can't find Ambience theme for XFCE out the in the Internet (while there are even couple of pretty good versions for Windows XP). Could you share a link? I even don't require everything (like controls and icons) look exactly like it does in original Ubuntu Ambiance, I just want window decorations (better with controls on the right though) and a colours scheme (for example dark menu bars instead of default blue ones).

PS: I'd prefer not to install Gnome and Metacity.

Answer (score 6):

I just made a theme that imitate exactly Ambiance theme used in Ubuntu, and built for Xubuntu. Check it out: http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php?content=141027

Answer (score 3):

I recently stumbled upon the best XFCE/LXDE versions of Ambiance and Radiance I've seen yet, put together by the RAVEfinity team. You can check them out at xfce-look:

http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+%26+Radiance+Themes+for+Xfce%2BOpen?content=146674

For the impatient, they can be installed thusly:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ambiance-xfce-lxde radiance-xfce-lxde
```

They look great and I haven't run into any of the bugs or oddities I've seen with the other Ambiance/Radiance knockoffs. They also provide some interesting "colored" versions of Ambiance and Radiance (which I haven't tried yet):

http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+%26+Radiance+Colors+Version?content=147891

Answer (score 2):

have you checked out [xfce-look.org](http://xfce-look.org/)? It has a lot of themes for you to choose from.

A few Ambiance themes are found here:

- [Ambiance Redefined III](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+Refined+III?content=133672)
- [Ambiance Elegancy](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+Elegancy?content=125792)

Most of the themes (including those two above) use GTK. You can sort through the KFCE themes on kfce-look.org though. Here are some similar to the Ambiance theme, though they aren't the same:

- [Axiom](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/axiom?content=90145)
- [Shiki Colors](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Shiki-Colors+for+xfwm?content=88913)

Comment: Of course I have checked out xfce-look.org. "Redefined III" and "Elegancy" are, as far as I understand, made for Metacity (Gnome's WM, XFCE uses XFWM and I don't want to change this). Even the author writes "I did not like some of the settings of the default Ambiance theme, so I changed the following..." which says that his intention was to modify the original "Ambiance", which only exists for Gnome. I just wonder why are those themes hosted on xfce-look while they are not XFCE themes.

Comment: "Axiom" and "Shiki-Colors" both notably differ from Ambiance. "Shiki-Colors" comes close though, maybe I'll use it, I haven't noticed it before.

Comment: I think you can just use Ambiance somehow for the windows, however I think you will have to find your own window decorator theme.

Comment: The two Ambiance themes use GTK which is different than Gnome. Both Gnome and XFCE use GTK.

Answer (score 1):

After 12.10 (quantal) the [Ravefinity PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ravefinity-project/+archive/ppa) has not been updated. But as of 14.04 (trusty), one can get their current Xfce Ambiance and Radiance themes from their [website](http://www.ravefinity.com/p/ambiance-radiance-for-xfce-lxde.html).